# Decomposition of real number into elements of null measure sets

Tags: measure-theory, cantor-set

Are there sets A and B such that any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ can be decomposed as $x = a+b$, $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, where the Lebesgue measure of $A$ and of $B$ is null.

There is an indication that this should follow from the fact that $C_q = \{z \in[0,1]; z_i\in\{0,2,\cdots,q-1\}\}$ has null measure for every $q \in \mathbb{N}$, where $z_i$ are the numbers in the q-adic expansion of $z$, that is $$z=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{z_i}{q^i}$$

Comment: This was asked recently on this site. Anyway, let $A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}(C+2n) $ and $B=C $, where $C $ is the Cantor set, and use that $C+C=[0,2] $.

Comment: Where was it asked recently? Can you please link it?

Comment: I finally found the question I had in mind. It is not the same, but one of the answers addresses your question. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2406155/462).

Answer (score 8):

Yes. The following example was given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153915/sum-of-sets-of-measure-zero) by Davide Giraudo.

> If $A$ is the set of real numbers such that in their proper binary expansion, the even terms are $0$, and $B$ the same with odd numbers, then $A$ and $B$ have measure $0$ but their sum is the whole real line

Comment: I do not understand the definition of sets $A$ and $B$. Can you give an example?

Comment: Can you give an indication of the proof of this fact?

Comment: For $n>0$ let $D(2n)$ be the set of  finite binary sequences of length $2n.$  For $z\in \mathbb Z$ and $d\in D(n)$ let $R(z,d)$ be the set of $x\in [z,z+1)$ that have $d$ as their first $2n$ binary digits to the right of the decimal point.  For distinct $d,d'\in D(2n)$ the sets $R(z,d'),R(z,d')$ are disjoint and each is a translate of the other so each has measure $4^{-n}.$ CONTINUED IN NEXT COMMENT.

Comment: CONTINUED. Let $E(2n)$ be the set of members of $D(2n)$ with $0$ in all even places. $E(2n)$ has $2^n$ members. Now $A\cap [z,z+1))\subset \cup_{d\in E(2n)}R(z,d)$ and the measure $m(\cup_{d\in E(2n)}R(z,d))=2^n4^{-n}=2^{-n}.$ So $m(A\cap [z,z+1)\leq 2^{-n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb N.$

Comment: Intuitively the probability that a sequence  of $2n$ coin-tosses will come up heads on every even-numbered toss  is $2^{-n}$ so the probability that any $x\in [z,z+1) $ belongs to A should be less than $2^{-n}$ for all $n.$..... I am taking $A$ as those reals that have $0$ in every even binary digit to the right of the decimal point.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the classical cantor set $C$, then
$$C-C = \{x-y\mid x,y\in C\} = [-1,1]$$

Comment: Sure, this is very easy to see. But I want it to form the Real Line, not the unitary interval.

Comment: @FranciscoMaion   You can extend $C$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$ by making it periodic with period 1. Then after extension, $C-C = \mathbb{R}$.